# Configuring GPU mining with CGminer

Tags: mining-pools, client, cgminer

I know GPU mining is looked down upon, but I cant afford an ASIC. SO I would like to know how to mine Bitcoin with CGminer using my gpu. Any help would be appreciated. I already am connected to a server, so I don't need help with that.

Comment: This won't work. Not only will the electricity cost much more than you earn, you will likely never reach the minimum amount needed to cash out from the pool. So you earn zero.

Comment: @Dr.Haribo I'm not to worried about electricity cause I usually use my schools. Any suggestion what I can do until I get an ASIC or two?

Comment: Maybe try some altcoin mining. You can't mine bitcoin with just a PC, since ASICs took over in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

CGMiner does not support GPU mining anymore because it is too inefficient to mine Bitcoin with. It does not make sense for the authors to continue GPU mining support so they stopped doing so and it is no longer possible to GPU mine with CGMiner.

Comment: You just use an old version of cgminer such as 3.7.2 . There's really no point from a profitability angle because ASICs exist now, but from technical feasibility angle it is possible still:  https://cryptomining-blog.com/460-download-cgminer-3-7-2-with-gpu-support-for-windows/

Comment: @Sun isn't that rather like mining coal from a worked out and backfilled open-cast mine using a broken teaspoon as your only tool? Its not exactly mining if there's no possibility of finding anything.

Comment: I have no clue why anyone would say GPU's aren't worth mining with... you sir are a troll Mr Chow. Actually GPU's are faster than most CPU's, not everyone has access to ASICS, or other high end systems. You are better off paying for processing time on gooogle's cloud and adding the cloudGPU drivers then using the additional CUDA processing to accelerate finding coin blockchains.. Most people aren't going to help you with Bitcoin or other mining because its not profitable for them to do so given that their is only a finite amount of coins available. It would be like asking a wallstreet dealer t

Comment: @AndrewKeim No, I am not trolling. It is not efficient to mine *Bitcoin* with GPUs because the difficulty is very high. The probability of receiving any payout is extremely low with a GPU. At no point did I say that CPU mining was efficient or better. No one is CPU mining either. For altcoins, yes, you can GPU mine. But that doesn't mean that it makes sense to GPU mine for Bitcoin.